# I uninstalled Compiz and now the Unity panels has disappeared

Tags: 11.04, unity, compiz, panel, ccsm

This is not my original question where they were completely transparent and are just not there.  I have reinstalled ccsm, but they are still not there.

I have tried `unity --reset` which I thought would help but it says that unity is not there.  I an ccsm in unity and I couldn't even turn on and off unity.  Why is it doing this and how can I stop it?  I know the shortcut keys for terminal and ccsm in ubuntu so I can adapt from there and in the GNOME classic side.  I have had lots of trouble with Natty and kind of don't like it.  I tried to uninstall ccsm for some more hard drive space not knowing that it was so closely attached to the OS.  I reinstalled it I think I deleted some crucial part of unity that control the panels.  I now need to install unity.  I tried `install unity` which didn't work and I need some command.

Comment: We need more detail on what you're doing here and what you want to accomplish. Your description sounds like you were trying to turn unity off in which case it you appeared to have shut it off or something.

Comment: You have only described what you tried to fix your problem. You need to describe the actual problem in more detail, and anything you remember from before the problem began that might be related.

Comment: sudo apt-get install compiz

Comment: Unity is a compiz plugin, you have to reinstall compiz with the unity plugin.

Comment: Thank you Daniel I think that is what I was looking for.  Sorry for being so vague.

Comment: I just need the location of that on the net then.

Comment: Ok. I got it and installed now what I need to know is why I can't see the panels.  This is not as my prior question.  The answer isn't the same(I already checked) and the panel isn't outlined with the shadow as with the prior.  I only know that it's there because it is outlined when I maximize a window.

Comment: It didn't work and I have given up and switched to openSUSE.  I don't like this new version of ubuntu and can't witch back and so I have decided to give up and switch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unity Panel depends on having Compiz. The following options for Unity are needed:

- OpenGL
- Composite
- Desktop Wall

You could logout and login again but remember to have compiz and those options activated for Unity Panel.

Since Unity Panel NEEDS Desktop Wall to do the hide/show effect, you can not activate the Cube, that is, the Rotating Cube Effect and the Desktop Cube since they disable the Desktop Wall, hence disabling Unity Panel, hence destroying the world (Of Unity) as we know it. Its horrible!

To go to this options just open Dash with <kbd>SUPER</kbd> or <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type `Compiz Settings`.